# Is it possible to encrypt and compress files on self-hosted runtime as part of ADF flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am looking for a way to first encrypt CSV files and then compress before executing the ADF copy flow. The encryption and compression needs to happen on the self-hosted IR.

To visualize this a bit

Step 1 - Kick-off the ADF flow

Step 2 - Encrypt the CSV files on Self-hosted IR

Step 3 - Compress the encrypted files on Self-hosted IR

Step 4 - Execute the copy flow in ADF to transmit the files from on-premise servers to Azure cloud

How can I achieve this through ADF flow?

Comment: Are you copying data from a local FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can encrypt and store credentials for your on-premises data stores (linked services with sensitive information) on a machine with self-hosted integration runtime. You can read more details in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/encrypt-credentials-self-hosted-integration-runtime).
2. With customer-managed keys, ADF can encrypts data at rest, including entity definitions and any data cached while runs are in progress. You can read more details in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/enable-customer-managed-key#prerequisites---configure-azure-key-vault-and-generate-keys).
3. If you are copying data from a local FTP server, you can use SFTP Linked Service to encrypt the files transfer.
   [image]
4. In the Copy activity, you can select **Compression type** at sink dataset, ADF will compress the files according to the compression type.
   [image]
   Select the compression type at sink dataset:
   [image]

Comment: It is requirement to encrypt the data before it is transmitted, so I cannot rely on SFTP. Also, I am not looking to encrypt the credentials, I am looking to encrypt the data.